# Sending an external email when the "Send" button is pushed in a 123ContactForm form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, sendgrid

**Background Info:** 
123ContactForm generates contact forms that you can embed in your site. I am using this tool because it allows the data to be sent to a 3rd party application that i use.

**What i am looking to achieve:**
Once the form is filled and the user pushes the "Send Email" button, i want the form to complete its normal function of recording the data into the 3rd party application and then send an email to a specified person, a static email address. 123ContactForm's normal functionality is to send the email to you, the admin of the form, but that is not what i want. I want this email to go to a third party.

**What i am trying:**
I am trying to get the one "send email" button to also open up a "mailto:test@test.com" or i am trying to use a service like sendgrid to send this email.

**The problem i ran into:**
123ContactForms gives me 3 options to embed this form. Javascript, Iframe, and HTML. Due to my lack of webdevelopment experience i am unable to find this button and attach the above mentioned functionality to it. By inspecting element i have found this code for the button but im not sure how to edit it to make it also send an email to a specified address.

```
<input onclick="this.style.display='none';insertPleaseWaitDiv(this,'Please wait...');  " type="submit" class="class123-button" id="id123-button-send" value="Send Email">
```

**Resources:**
A test form: http://www.123contactform.com/form-1522070/Contact-Lead-Form

Javascript Embed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var servicedomain="www.123contactform.com"; var frmRef=''; try { frmRef=window.top.location.href; } catch(err) {}; var cfJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://"); document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + servicedomain + "/includes/easyXDM.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); frmRef=encodeURIComponent(frmRef).replace('%26','[%ANDCHAR%]'); document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + servicedomain + "/jsform-1522070.js?ref="+frmRef+"' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); </script>
```

IFrame Embed:

```
<iframe allowTransparency="true" style="min-height:300px; height:inherit; overflow:auto;" width="100%" id="contactform123" name="contactform123" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="http://www.123contactform.com/my-contact-form-1522070.html">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes. The contact form cannot be displayed. Please use another contact method (phone, fax etc)</p>
</iframe>
```

HTML Embed:

```
<!-- www.123contactform.com script begins here -->

<!-- formalign --><center>

<link href="https://dflzqrzibliy5.cloudfront.net/modules/calculations/form/css/form.calculations.css?9009" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />

<script type="text/javascript">
var cfJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + "dflzqrzibliy5.cloudfront.net/modules/calculations/form/js/form.calculations.js?9009' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var formrules=new Array(0);

//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cfJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + "dflzqrzibliy5.cloudfront.net/includes/interactive123cf.js?9009' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .focus { background: #FEF1C1; }
    .class123-label { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: small; color: #FFFFFF;}
    .headline { color: #FFFFFF; }
    .class123-labelmic { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: xx-small; color: #666666; }
    .class123-labelinfo { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: xx-small; color: #666666; }
    .class123-sidebyside { float:left; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
    .class123-twocol { float:left; width:45%; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
    .class123-threecol { float:left; width:30%; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
    .class123-likert_style_li { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; top:0px; padding:0px; /*width:20%;*/ height:50px; margin:0px; font:79%/100% verdana; font-weight:bold; background:#f8f8f8; zoom:1; *display:inline; }
    .class123-likert_style_li2 { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; top:0px; padding:0px; /*width:20%;*/ height:50px; margin:0px; font:79%/100% verdana; zoom:1; *display:inline; }
    .class123-select { height:1.6em; }



    .class123-savereturn { background: none; border: medium none; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; padding:5px 10px;}
    .class123-goback { background: none; border: medium none; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; padding:5px 10px; color: #C80042;}
    .class123-pbline { display:none; }
    .class123-pbprev { background: none; border: medium none; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; }
    .class123_maintable {}
    .class123-pagination { float:left; width:99%; /*min-width:550px;*/ font-size:10px; margin:0px; margin-bottom:10px; }
    #mainform123 .class123-pagination { background-color:#FFFFFF; }.class123-progresscircle { margin:0px !importat; background: #CCC; width: 24px; height: 24px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; float:left; }
    .class123-progresscircleactive { margin:0px !importat; background:#FEF1C1; width: 24px; height: 24px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; }
    .class123-progresstext { display:table-cell; height:100%; width: 24px; text-align:center; padding-top:3px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
    .class123-progressPercDiv { float:left; width:100%; margin:0px !important; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:2px; }
    #mainform123 .class123-progressPercDiv { background:#FFFFFF; }

    .class123-progressPercBar { float:left; text-align:right; line-height:23px; padding-right:4px; font-weight:bold; height: 24px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin:0px !importat; background:#FEF1C1;}
    #mainform123 .class123-progressPercBar { background:#FEF1C1; }

    .class123-pagename { float:left; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height:14px; margin-left:5px; max-width:85px; margin-top:5px; }
    .currentPageActive { display:block; }
    .currentPageInactive { display:none; }
    .hideAlternate { display:block; height0px;width:0px; overflow:hidden !important;padding:0px;margin:0px;pointer-events: none;position:absolute;left:-2000px;top:0px;}
    .formdefaultbutcolor { background-color: #FFFFFF }
    .formnotextButton { width:150px; }

    .fontbold { font-weight: bold; }
    .fontitalic { font-style: italic; }
    .fontbolditalic { font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; }
    .requiredspan { font-family: Verdana; font-size:10px; color:#FF0000; margin-left:3px; }
    .requiredfield:after{content: "\0000a0*";color:#FF0000;font-size:10px;font-family:Verdana;}
    .columntable tr td { padding:5px; }
    .class123_maintable { text-align: left; }
    .formdefaultbut { display:inline; list-style:none; margin-right:4px; color:#fff; border:none; cursor:pointer; border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; font-weight:bold; vertical-align: middle; }
    .footerLink13:link,.footerLink13:visited,.footerLink13:active { font-size:small!important;color:#404040!important; text-decoration:underline!important;}
    .footerLink13:hover{font-size:small!important;color:#FFFFFF!important;text-decoration:none!important;background-color:#C80042!important;}

    /* NEW STYLES BEGIN */
    .maintable_centered { margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%; }
    .divonecolumn { width:48% !important; float:left; display:block; margin-right:3px; }

    .optionscontainer { width:100%; display:block; float: left; text-align:left; }
    .optionscontainer.pagination {margin-top:6px;}
    .errormsg, .fielderror { color: #FF0000 !important; }
    .customerror { background-color: #FFFFFF !important; border-color: #FF0000 !important; }
    div[id^="class123-bicTOSFrame"] { background-color:white; overflow-y: auto; } /* height not needed anymore */

    .timer-container {float:right; }
    .timer-container.timer-locked {margin-bottom:-27px;}
    #form-timer { padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px; float:right;background-color: #FFFFFF; color:#FFFFFF; border-radius:3px;overflow:hidden;margin-top:2px;  }
    #form-timer .countdown {float:right;}
    #form-timer span { line-height: 24px;   padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; }
    #form-timer span.hours-label,#form-timer span.minutes-label { border-right:#FFFFFF solid 1px;padding-right:6px;margin-right:5px; }
    #form-timer span.hours-label,#form-timer span.minutes-label,#form-timer span.seconds-label  { font-size:12px;padding-left:2px;}
    #form-timer span.hours-value,#form-timer span.minutes-value,#form-timer span.seconds-value { font-size:15px; }
    #form-timer .timer-clock {float:right; padding-right:7px;font-size:15px;}
    @media only screen and (max-width:640px){
        .timer-container.timer-locked {margin-bottom:0px !important;}
        }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
        .char-limit-mobile {
            display:inline !important;
        }
    }

    .fieldcontainer { float: left; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; } /* OLD: margin-bottom:3px; also had display:none, which caused bug on form 376500 */
    .fieldcontainer div .rowleft, .fieldcontainer div .rowright { display:block; float: left; }

    .fieldcontainer .rowleft { margin:6px 1%; width:24%; }
    .fieldcontainer .rowright { margin:6px 1%; width:72%; }
    .fieldcontainer .rowup { margin:3px 0.5%; width: 96%; float:left; }
    .fieldcontainer .rowdown { margin:3px 0.5%; width:96%; float:left; }
    .fieldcontainer .uberfieldlat { margin:3px 1%; }
    .fieldcontainer #printlink { margin-left: 0.5%; }
    .class123-separ-row { float:left; width:100%; background-color: transparent; }

    .fieldwidth100 { float:left; width:100%; }
    .fieldwidth90  { float:left; width:90%; }
    .fieldwidth85  { float:left; width:85%; }
    .fieldwidth80  { float:left; width:80%; }
    .fieldwidth75  { float:left; width:75%; }
    .fieldwidth70  { float:left; width:70%; }
    .fieldwidth65  { float:left; width:65%; }
    .fieldwidth60  { float:left; width:60%; }
    .fieldwidth55  { float:left; width:55%; }
    .fieldwidth50  { float:left; width:50%; }
    .fieldwidth45  { float:left; width:45%; }
    .fieldwidth40  { float:left; width:40%; }
    .fieldwidth35  { float:left; width:35%; }
    .fieldwidth30  { float:left; width:30%; }
    .fieldwidth25  { float:left; width:25%; }
    .fieldwidth20  { float:left; width:20%; }
    .fieldwidth15  { float:left; width:15%; }
    .fieldwidth10  { float:left; width:10%; }   

    .sortabledemo .fieldwidth90, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth80, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth70, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth60, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth50, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth40, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth30, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth20, .sortabledemo .fieldwidth10
    { background-image:url("/images3/bg-field-container.png");background-repeat:repeat-x;position:relative;background-position:bottom; }
     .thebuttons .divonecolumn.second { padding:6px; }
    .fieldcontainer img.tcalIcon{ max-width:100px!important; }
    .fieldcontainer img, select { max-width:99% !important; } /* fix for Samsung devices */
    #formeditor_page #basicoptions .ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { -moz-appearance: menulist-button; height: 19px; margin-right: -3px; margin-top: -1px; padding: 0; width: 15px; }
    #formeditor_page #advancedoptions .ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { -moz-appearance: menulist-button; height: 19px; margin-right: -3px; margin-top: -1px; padding: 0; width: 15px; }
    #formeditor_page #basicoptions .ui-multiselect { width:185px!important; background-color:white; border-style:inset; border-radius:0px; color:black; font-weight:normal; padding:0px; -moz-appearance: menulist; -webkit-appearance:menulist; font-size:13px; height:20px; }
    #formeditor_page #advancedoptions .ui-multiselect { width:185px!important; background-color:white; border-style:inset; border-radius:0px; color:black; font-weight:normal; padding:0px; -moz-appearance: menulist; -webkit-appearance:menulist; font-size:13px; height:20px; }
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        #formeditor_page #basicoptions .ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { margin-right:0px!important; margin-top:0px!important; width:19px!important;  }
        #formeditor_page #advancedoptions .ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { margin-right:0px!important; margin-top:0px!important; width:19px!important;  }
        #formeditor_page #basicoptions .ui-multiselect {border-color:#c3c3c3; -webkit-appearance:menulist;}
        #formeditor_page #advancedoptions .ui-multiselect {border-color:#c3c3c3; -webkit-appearance:menulist;}
    }

    .class123-firstname, .class123-lastname, .class123-subfieldMiddle { width:95px; margin-right:10px;  }
    .class123-subfieldInitials { width:45px; margin-right:10px; }
    .class123-address { max-width:400px; }
    .class123-hidden { display:none !important; }
    /* NEW STYLES END */
</style>
   <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
    .class123-likert_style_li2 {height:56px;}
    </style>
    <![endif]--><script type="text/javascript">
    var fid=1522070;
    var curr='';
    var preview_iframe=0;
    var real_time=0;
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var selectedfield='';
var multiPageCurent=1;
var multiPageTotal=1;
function InputActions(field,id) {
    window.stopCalculate=true;
    var textcolor='#FFFFFF';
    var hltextcolor='#000000';
    $('.class123-labelinfo.class123-labelhidden').addClass('hidden_instruction');
    $(field).parents('.fieldcontainer').last().find('.class123-labelinfo').removeClass('hidden_instruction');
    //var calendar = $('img[title="Close Calendar"]').trigger('click');

     lastactionobj=field;

    if (id==selectedfield) { /* alert('do nothing'); */ }
    else
        {
        // first we unhighlight the previous field, if any
        if (selectedfield!='')
            {
            //$('.tcalIcon').closest('.fieldcontainer').css('background','none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff');
            lid=selectedfield;
            lidsec=lid.replace('row','rowsec');

            // reparam culoare textlabels
            var tr=document.getElementById(lid);

            if (document.getElementsByClassName)
                {
            var textlabels = tr.getElementsByClassName('class123-label');
            for (j=0;j<textlabels.length;j++)
                textlabels[j].style.color=textcolor;
                }
                else
                {
                var textlabels=tr.getElementsByTagName('label');
                for (j=0;j<textlabels.length;j++)
                    if (textlabels[j].className.indexOf('class123-label')>-1) textlabels[j].style.color=textcolor;
                }
            var oldbg='';
            if (document.getElementById('errorflag'+lid)!=null)
                oldbg=document.getElementById('errorflag'+lid).value;

            // reparam culoare bg td
            var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for (j=0;j<tds.length;j++)
                tds[j].parentNode.parentNode.style.background=oldbg;

            // reparam culoare bg td sec
            if (document.getElementById(lidsec) != null)
                {
                var trsec=document.getElementById(lidsec);
                tds = trsec.getElementsByTagName('div');
                for (j=0;j<tds.length;j++)
                    tds[j].parentNode.parentNode.style.background=oldbg;
                }
            }
        // then we highlight the new one
        selectedfield=id;

        lid=id;
        lidsec=lid.replace('row','rowsec');

        // modificam culoare textlabels
        var tr=document.getElementById(lid);
        if (document.getElementsByClassName)
            {
        var textlabels = tr.getElementsByClassName('class123-label');
        for (j=0;j<textlabels.length;j++)
            textlabels[j].style.color=hltextcolor;
            }
            else
            {
            var textlabels=tr.getElementsByTagName('label');
            for (j=0;j<textlabels.length;j++)
                if (textlabels[j].className.indexOf('class123-label')>-1) textlabels[j].style.color=hltextcolor;
            }

        // modificam culoare bg td
        var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('div');for (j=0;j<tds.length;j++)
                tds[j].parentNode.parentNode.style.background='#FEF1C1';

            // modificam culoare bg td sec
            if (document.getElementById(lidsec) != null)
                {
                var trsec=document.getElementById(lidsec);
                tds = trsec.getElementsByTagName('div');
                for (j=0;j<tds.length;j++)
                    tds[j].parentNode.parentNode.style.background='#FEF1C1';
                }
        }
    // now the field rules

    InputRules2('beginning','0','0');
}
function IsFullDateEntered(c_id) {
if((document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-1') != null)&&(document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-2')!=null)&&(document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-3')!=null))
    {
    if  ((document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-1').value!='')&&(document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-2').value!='')&&(document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-3').value!=''))
        document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id).value=document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-1').value+'/'+document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-2').value+'/'+document.getElementById('id123-control'+c_id+'-3').value;
    }
}
//-->
</script><form  class="form" onsubmit="RefreshFrameHeight(1); return checkSubmitAllowed();" action="http://www.123contactform.com/form-1522070/Contact-Lead-Form" id="mainform123" method="post" name="mainform123" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="verify"/><input type="hidden" name="special_autoresponder" id="special_autoresponder" value=""/><input type="hidden" name="language" value="en"/><input type="hidden" name="languageChanged" value="no"/><div class="class123_maintable " style="min-width:150px; " >
<script type='text/javascript'>
var  js_ctype_arr = new Array();
var  js_cobject_arr = new Array();
js_ctype_arr['cid13526719']=0;
js_cobject_arr['cid13526719']=0;
js_ctype_arr['cid13735089']=0;
js_cobject_arr['cid13735089']=0;
js_ctype_arr['cid13737638']=0;
js_cobject_arr['cid13737638']=0;

</script>
<!-- Column One begins (aux) -->
<div><div class='divonecolumn'>

<!-- Column One InnerTable begins (aux) -->
<div class="columntable" style="border-top:0px;" cellpading="6" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<!-- fieldcontainer -->
<div id="fieldcontainer1" class="fieldcontainer currentPage1 currentPageActive  fieldwidth100     "  style=" ">
<div id="row1" class="currentPage1 currentPageActive">
<div class="rowleft"  style="text-align:left; ">
<label class="class123-label class123-fieldname class123-labelAligned fontbold " id="id123-title13526719" style="position: relative;" for="id123-control13526719" ></label></div>
<div class="rowright" align="left" style=""><input type="hidden" id="errorflagrow1" value=""/><input id="id123-control13526719" name="control13526719"    onclick=" InputActions(this,'row1');" onkeyup=" InputActions(this,'row1');    " onchange="InputRules(13526719); ;  "onfocus="InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13526719', 'First Name', 'focus', '#000000', '#666666');" onblur="InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13526719', 'First Name', 'blur', '#000000', '#666666');"  type="text" value="First Name" style="width:280px; max-width:96% !important; position:relative;" />
</div></div>
</div>
<!-- fieldcontainer ends -->

<!-- fieldcontainer -->
<div id="fieldcontainer2" class="fieldcontainer currentPage1 currentPageActive  fieldwidth100     "  style=" ">
<div id="row2" class="currentPage1 currentPageActive">
<div class="rowleft"  style="text-align:left; ">
<label class="class123-label class123-fieldname class123-labelAligned fontbold " id="id123-title13735089" style="position: relative;" for="id123-control13735089" ></label></div>
<div class="rowright" align="left" style=""><input type="hidden" id="errorflagrow2" value=""/><input id="id123-control13735089" name="control13735089"    onclick=" InputActions(this,'row2');" onkeyup=" InputActions(this,'row2');    " onchange="InputRules(13735089); ;  "onfocus="InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13735089', 'Last Name', 'focus', '#000000', '#666666');" onblur="InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13735089', 'Last Name', 'blur', '#000000', '#666666');"  type="text" value="Last Name" style="width:160px; max-width:96% !important; position:relative;" />
</div></div>
</div>
<!-- fieldcontainer ends -->

</div>
<!-- Column One InnerTable ends -->

</div>
<!-- Column One ends -->

<!-- Column Two begins (aux)-->
<div class='divonecolumn'>

<!-- Column Two InnerTable begins (aux) -->
<div class="columntable" style="border-top:0px;" cellpading="6" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<!-- fieldcontainer -->
<div id="fieldcontainer3" class="fieldcontainer currentPage1 currentPageActive  fieldwidth100     "  style=" ">
<div id="row3" class="currentPage1 currentPageActive">
<div class="rowleft"  style="text-align:left; ">
<label class="class123-label class123-fieldname class123-labelAligned fontbold " id="id123-title13737638" style="position: relative;" for="id123-control13737638" ></label></div>
<div class="rowright" align="left" style=""><input type="hidden" id="errorflagrow3" value=""/><input id="id123-control13737638" name="control13737638"    onclick=" InputActions(this,'row3');" onkeyup=" InputActions(this,'row3');    " onchange="InputRules(13737638); ;  "onfocus="InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13737638', 'Email', 'focus', '#000000', '#666666');" onblur="InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13737638', 'Email', 'blur', '#000000', '#666666');"  type="text" value="Email" style="width:160px; max-width:96% !important; position:relative;" />
</div></div>
</div>
<!-- fieldcontainer ends -->

<script type="text/javascript"> var f_fixedamount='0';
    var nr_fields=3;
    this.nr_fields=nr_fields;
    this.form_is_quiz='';
    var calc_fields=0;
    </script>
</div>
<!-- Column Two InnerTable ends -->

</div></div>
<!-- Column Two ends -->
<div id="checkout_form_con" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"></div>
<!-- Buttons begin here -->
<div id="fieldcontainer4" class='fieldcontainer thebuttons' style="">
<div class="currentPage1 currentPageActive"><div class='divonecolumn first'> </div><div class='divonecolumn second' align="left"><input type="hidden" name="go_back_and_edit" id="go_back_and_edit" value="0" /><input OnClick="  this.style.display='none'; insertPleaseWaitDiv(this,'Please wait...');  " type="submit" class="class123-button"  id="id123-button-send"  value="Send Email"/> 
</div></div>
</div>
<!-- fieldcontainer ends -->
<!-- Buttons end here -->
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="f33hgmlv4sg6ff0hodh9hta6d6"/>
<div style="height:1px; display: none; visibility: hidden;">
<input type="text" name="email"/>
</div>


        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfields" id="hiddenfields" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfields_pages" id="hiddenfields_pages" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="activepage" id="activepage" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="totalpages" id="totalpages" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="nextpagenr" id="nextpagenr" value="2"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="prevpagenr" id="prevpagenr" value="0"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        InputRules('firsttime')
        </script><input type="hidden" name="usage" value="e"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13526719', 'First Name', 'blur', '#000000', '#666666');InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13735089', 'Last Name', 'blur', '#000000', '#666666');InputSetDefaultValue('id123-control13737638', 'Email', 'blur', '#000000', '#666666');</script><p align='center' style='float:left; width:100%'><font size="1" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" color="#FFFFFF"><a href="http://www.123contactform.com">Email form</a> generated by 123ContactForm</font></p></center><!-- formalign ends -->
<script type="text/javascript">multiPageTotal=1;</script>
<p style='clear:both'></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 123contactform is asking me to upgrade before I can add the smtp option.

To send 123contactform through Sendgrid you would enable the option 'Send emails through your own SMTP server'  then enter your Sendgrid user/pass and the smtp server smtp.sendgrid.net to send.

Also if you want simple functionality from this form you could use something like this php example https://gist.github.com/Burrer/1581edff337eb89ee1e1

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i need to use 123ContactForm because it allows me to send information directly to a third party app. I will try the smtp option

Comment: I do have access to the SMTP option but who will this email be sent from?

Comment: That php example you included. Could it be altered to use this api: http://www.123contactform.com/docs/123contactform-api-php-example-script/

Comment: You could add that SendGrid php script to this php script but it would probably make more sense to enable to the 'Send emails through your own SMTP server' and also use the the php to webhook script. The 'from' address would most likely be something specific to you and your business like a admin@yourdomain.com or something.